# Using system variable within string to get file version in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, version

I am trying to get something like this to work but cannot figure it out.

```
(Get-Item env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

I am getting an error that it does not exist, though I know it does.

If I run the same thing with a known logged in user like below,

```
(Get-Item c:\users\jonesb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

I get the versioning I am looking for.  I will be running this script on thousands of machines and I don't know who will be logged in to each machine.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`env:userprofile` expands to `env:\userprofile`. This is a PSDrive, which you can access with Cmdlets like `Get-Item`, but it does not expand in strings. What you need to do is to use the variable `$env:userprofile`.

```
(Get-Item $env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```